# Problem filling Django template in googleappengine Loader

Tags: django-templates

I am trying to test a googleapengine project locally, but am getting errors loading templates:

My settings.py contains TEMPLATE_LOADERS with  Loader wrappers:

e.g. django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader

but *there is* no Loader wrapper class in the bundled filesystem.py file within

xx/google_appengine/lib/django/django/template/loaders/

so I'm getting this error:

Exception Type: ImproperlyConfigured
Exception Value: Module "django.template.loaders.filesystem" does not define a "Loader" callable template source loader
Exception Location: in xxxx/google_appengine/lib/django/django/template/loader.py in find_template_source, line 60

Answer (score 1):

It is possible you are using a settings.py file that you created with a newer version of Django, on a system that has an older version installed.  The template loaders changed, and settings.py cannot find the new module.